# Balanced payment returning status:400 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, balanced-payments

I am having trouble with the balanced javascript to send the credit card information through balanced.js. The response appears to be a 400 response even though I havent tried to jQuery.post it. I am using rails 4 and coffeescript. I am using the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/balanced/ZwhrA/.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#cc-submit').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    marketplaceuri = "TEST-MP5o4Bt04Oo1XBYKVLVV3xWt"

    balanced.init(marketplaceuri)

    responseTarget = "localhost:3000/events/7/tablecharges/new"

    payload = {
    name: $('#cc-name').val()
    card_number: $('#cc-number').val()
    expiration_month: $('#cc-expiration-month').val()
    expiration_year: $('#cc-expiration-year').val()
    security_code: $('#cc-ccv').val()
    }

    card = balanced.card.create(payload, (response) ->
        if (response.status == 201 && response.uri)
            alert('respone.id')
        else
            alert(JSON.stringify(response, false, 4)))
```

Comment: ??? Running your jsfiddle does not produce 400 response. Is there something special to do to trigger the error?

Comment: What was the text of the 400 response you got? It should tell you exactly which parameter was malformed.

Comment: I figured out the answer thanks!